# How to register a custom speech recognition service?

Tags: android, android-service

I created a simple speech recognition service: for this purpose I created a subclass of `android.speech.RecognitionService` and I created an activity to start and stop this service.

My custom speech recognition service trivially uses the default speech recognizer, because my goal is simply to understand how the `RecognitionService` and `RecognitionService.Callback` classes work.

```
public class SimpleVoiceService extends RecognitionService {

    private SpeechRecognizer m_EngineSR;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.i("SimpleVoiceService", "Service started");
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.i("SimpleVoiceService", "Service stopped");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancel(Callback listener) {
        m_EngineSR.cancel();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStartListening(Intent recognizerIntent, Callback listener) {
        m_EngineSR.setRecognitionListener(new VoiceResultsListener(listener));
        m_EngineSR.startListening(recognizerIntent);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStopListening(Callback listener) {
        m_EngineSR.stopListening();
    }


    /**
     * 
     */
    private class VoiceResultsListener implements RecognitionListener {

        private Callback m_UserSpecifiedListener;

        /**
         * 
         * @param userSpecifiedListener
         */
        public VoiceResultsListener(Callback userSpecifiedListener) {
            m_UserSpecifiedListener = userSpecifiedListener;
        }

        @Override
        public void onBeginningOfSpeech() {
            try {
                m_UserSpecifiedListener.beginningOfSpeech();
            } catch (RemoteException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onBufferReceived(byte[] buffer) {
            try {
                m_UserSpecifiedListener.bufferReceived(buffer);
            } catch (RemoteException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onEndOfSpeech() {
            try {
                m_UserSpecifiedListener.endOfSpeech();
            } catch (RemoteException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(int error) {
            try {
                m_UserSpecifiedListener.error(error);
            } catch (RemoteException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onEvent(int eventType, Bundle params) { ; }

        @Override
        public void onPartialResults(Bundle partialResults) {
            try {
                m_UserSpecifiedListener.partialResults(partialResults);
            } catch (RemoteException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onReadyForSpeech(Bundle params) {
            try {
                m_UserSpecifiedListener.readyForSpeech(params);
            } catch (RemoteException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onResults(Bundle results) {
            try {
                m_UserSpecifiedListener.results(results);
            } catch (RemoteException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onRmsChanged(float rmsdB) {
            try {
                m_UserSpecifiedListener.rmsChanged(rmsdB);
            } catch (RemoteException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

I start and stop the service using the following activity.

```
public class VoiceServiceStarterActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Button startButton = new Button(this);
        startButton.setText("Start the service");
        startButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) { startVoiceService(); }
        });
        Button stopButton = new Button(this);
        stopButton.setText("Stop the service");
        stopButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) { stopVoiceService(); }
        });
        LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
        layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        layout.addView(startButton);
        layout.addView(stopButton);
        setContentView(layout);
    }

    private void startVoiceService() {
        startService(new Intent(this, SimpleVoiceService.class));
    }

    private void stopVoiceService() {
        stopService(new Intent(this, SimpleVoiceService.class));
    }
}
```

Finally I declared my service on the `AndroidManifest.xml` (see VoiceRecognition sample within Android SDK folder).

```
<service android:name="SimpleVoiceService"
         android:label="@string/service_name" >

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.speech.RecognitionService" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

Then I installed this application on an Android device and I start it:
 - when I start the service, it starts properly;
 - when I stop it, it stops properly.

But if I launch the following code in a another activity, the `activities` `List` contains only an element, which is the default speech recognizer.

```
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
List<ResolveInfo> activities = pm.queryIntentActivities(
            new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH), 0);
```

Why is my speech recognizer not returned among those present in the system?

Comment: Does this enable us to override 'Google Now' default RecognitionService? I mean, can I hook my own extended recognition service for google now?

Comment: Were your onStartListening Started working when you start SimpleVoiceSearch Service ? @enzom83

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want `queryIntentActivities(new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH), 0)` to pick up your activity (`VoiceServiceStarterActivity`) then you have to declare in your app's Manifest that this activity handles `RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH`, like this

```
<activity android:name="VoiceServiceStarterActivity">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.speech.action.RECOGNIZE_SPEECH" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
  </intent-filter>
  ...
</activity>
```

For more concrete code have a look at the project [Kõnele](http://kaljurand.github.io/K6nele/) ([source code](https://github.com/Kaljurand/K6nele)) which is essentially an open source implementation of the interfaces via which speech recognition is provided on Android, i.e. it covers:

- ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH
- ACTION_WEB_SEARCH
- RecognitionService

and uses open source speech recognition servers.

Comment: I do not understand why I should create a new activity. Currently I have an activity (`VoiceDemoActivity`) that handles the default speech recognizer through a `SpeechRecognizer` object. In order to use a custom voice recognition service, I have to create a new `SpeechRecognizer` object specifying a `ComponentName` object in the `createSpeechRecognizer` method: I suppose that this `ComponentName` should refer to the custom voice recognizer service, so I created a new `RecognitionService` class. Why do I need to implement another activity that can handle the `ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH` intent?

Comment: I improved my answer a bit, maybe it made it a bit more clear.

Comment: @Kaarel I really like what you did in Kõnele (although I don't know the Estonian language). I downloaded the source code from github in order to learn by example how to implement my own (English only) but it wouldn't build out of the box and the released app itself (downloaded from Google Play) gets stuck in *"Transcribing..."*. Where can I learn more about the structure of your code (3 different packages) and *why* it is implemented the way it is? Thanks!

Comment: @ripopenid Thanks! Kõnele is actually language-independent, but it's true that the main focus is currently on Estonian. The default server that Kõnele uses also supports English but only in the case of grammar-based speech recognition (http://kaljurand.github.io/Grammars/). Please report any bugs that you find (and also lack of documentation) at https://code.google.com/p/recognizer-intent/issues/list I can then respond to it as part of the bug report.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to use **createSpeechRecognizer(Context context, ComponentName serviceComponent)**