# onStartListening when is it called?

Tags: java, android, service, speech-recognition, voice-recognition

I'm working on an android application which is basically a service to convert speech in to text as a background process, I'm getting help from [How to register a custom speech recognition service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9997720/how-to-register-a-custom-speech-recognition-service) but I'm unable to know when `onStartListening()` is called.

Signature:

```
protected void onStartListening(Intent recognizerIntent, Callback listener)
```

Can any one can help or help me add more statements in the code given in that link so that I can recognize the speech in to text and show it in the toast?

Answer (score 0):

In general, there are 2 kinds of apps:

- apps that direct the user to convert audio into text, but don't actually implement the speech recognition part but just do the UI part (microphone button, VU visualizer) (let us call them *app1*);
- apps that actually convert audio into text, either on the device or by calling a cloud service, and to make themselves available to *app1*, they extend `RecognitionService` (let us call them *app2*).

Since you mention "toast" (i.e. a UI element), I guess you want to implement *app1*?

*app1* needs to do the following:

```
Intent intent = ...
SpeechRecognizer recognizer = ...
recognizer.setRecognitionListener(new RecognitionListener() { ... });
recognizer.startListening(intent)
```

Based on the specified *intent* and taking into account the user settings, Android finds a suitable *app2* to service *app1*.

*app2* extends the abstract class `RecognitionService`, i.e. it needs to implement a bunch of methods, among them `onStartListening`. The latter is called by Android when *app1* calls `startListening`.

As the author of *app1* you just need to provide the input details to the recognizer using the various intent extras, provide the handling of the output of the recognizer using the methods of the interface `RecognitionListener`, and start the *app2* using `startListening`.

Comment: @TàýýábHùsśâįñ Can you update your question with more detail, e.g. your implementation of `onStartListening` and how do you register the service in the manifest. From the current version of the question I don't quite understand where do you get stuck...

Comment: I have created a service while extending with RecognitionService. When the service is started, onStartListening method is never called. How will it start working. ?

Comment: @GauravArora Can you provide more details, ideally as part of a new question